# How to add certain number of strings from one list to another in c#

Tags: c#, string, list, c#-4.0

What I am trying to do is make two lists containing some number of students each. I want to ask the user how many students they want to send from group1 to group2. After the user's input, the program should remove that amount of students from the first list(group1) and add them to the second(group2).

Here is what I have written so far. my problem is I don't know how to add a certain number of strings from one list to another.
till now I only did add all elements from one group to another but not a certain number of them.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var groupOne = new List<string>() {"student_G1_01", "student_G1_02", "student_G1_03", "student_G1_04", "student_G1_05" };
            var groupTwo = new List<string>() { "student_G2_01", "student_G2_02", "student_G2_03", "student_G2_04", "student_G2_05", "student_G2_06" };

          
            Console.WriteLine("Student of group 1:");
            foreach (var strudent in groupOne)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(strudent);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n total number of students:" + groupOne.Count);



            Console.WriteLine("\n -------------- \n");



            Console.WriteLine("Students of group 2:");
            foreach(var student in groupTwo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(student);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n total number of students:" + groupTwo.Count);



            Console.WriteLine("\n -------------- \n");


            //adding all the students from group2 to group1 

            groupOne.AddRange(groupTwo);


            foreach (var strudent in groupOne)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(strudent);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n total number of students:" + groupOne.Count);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it was tested

```
var groupOne = new List<string>() { "student_G1_01", "student_G1_02", "student_G1_03", "student_G1_04", "student_G1_05" };
var groupTwo = new List<string>() { "student_G2_01", "student_G2_02", "student_G2_03", "student_G2_04", "student_G2_05", "student_G2_06" };

    var userInput = 3; // user input
    var take= groupOne.Take(userInput);
    groupTwo.AddRange(take);
   groupOne.RemoveRange(0,userInput) ;
    
     Console.WriteLine("------Group 1-------");
    foreach (var group in groupOne)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(group);
    }
   Console.WriteLine("------Group 2-------");
    foreach (var group in groupTwo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(group);
    }
```

test result

```
------Group 1-------
student_G1_04
student_G1_05
------Group 2-------
student_G2_01
student_G2_02
student_G2_03
student_G2_04
student_G2_05
student_G2_06
student_G1_01
student_G1_02
student_G1_03
```

Comment: Thank You so much ! it worked. that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @RastaMosi You are welcome!

Comment: I was just trying the same code you wrote, I copied the whole thing exactly but the output is different from what you have written. in the output, 3 students are removed from group one but only 2 are added to group 2, and also the two that are added in group 2 are exactly the same as the ones that is left In group 1.

Comment: the output is basically this => group1 : "student_G1_04
student_G1_05" .  group2: student_G2_01
student_G2_02
student_G2_03
student_G2_04
student_G2_05
student_G2_06 student_G1_04
student_G1_05

Comment: @RastaMosi thanks for feedback, I just copied from here and tested my code again and get the same ouput.  I am sorry but I can't imagine why you have such a different result. Just copy my code and completely replace your code inside of Main.

Comment: @RastaMosi But the answer you selected has a bug. It doesn't  remove selected students from groupOne.

Comment: I did copy the same thing but anyway it's all good now I use another answer given and now it's fine. I appreciated your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var groupOne = new List<string>() {"student_G1_01", "student_G1_02", "student_G1_03", "student_G1_04", "student_G1_05" };
            var groupTwo = new List<string>() { "student_G2_01", "student_G2_02", "student_G2_03", "student_G2_04", "student_G2_05", "student_G2_06" };
        
            var userInput = 3; // user input
            groupTwo.AddRange(groupOne.Take(userInput));
          
            foreach(var group in groupTwo){
              Console.WriteLine(group);  
            }             
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer has a bug. You didn't remove students from groupOne